# Estimating Percentiles for Weibull(ish) distribution

Tags: hypothesis-testing, estimation, nonparametric

I have sample data from a population - I need to estimate the 90th, 50th, 30th percentiles - so that I can compare these values to estimates from another population and see if there is a significant difference.

I did not want to make any assumptions about the distribution type so I first went along with a non-parametric bootstrap based method. Using this method I'm able to calculate confidence intervals for percentiles at some Alpha. Great!

But some problems are:

1. My sample size can be huge - anywhere from 10,000 to 100,000,000. Makes the whole process very computationally expensive.
2. I don't think there are any well known methods to calculate Power for bootstrap method. Because of that, I don't really know how many data-points (sample size) I need to make my conclusions.
3. I'm seeing too many Type I errors...

So I thought I'll try fitting my data to a distribution and then use parametric estimation.

```
library(fitdistrplus)
fit.weibull <- fitdist(x, "weibull")
plot(fit.weibull)
```

[image]

Does this seem like a good fit? The 'peak' of my distribtion is far above the fitted function.

Can I use parametric methods of estimation of percentiles on a weibull distribution - on my data? Not that I know of any such methods off the top of my head.

Comment: I don't understand the use of bootstrap in this circumstance. Why not just use the sample percentiles as estimates for the actual percentiles.  In estimating a Weibull  distribution I would assume you estimated the parameters based on the data (probably by maximum likelihood. The p-p plot you show could indicate a good fit if the deviations from the straight line are within the limits of random noise.

Comment: >I don't understand the use of bootstrap in this circumstance. Why not just use the sample percentiles as estimates for the actual percentiles. - how else would I calculate the Confidence interval?